# How to pass Dictionary<string, string> object in some method

Tags: c#, dictionary

Can somebody give an example of how i pass Dictionary object in some method.???

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can pass a dictionary like a normal argument:

```
private void MyMethod(Dictionary<string,string> myDictionary) { 
    //code 
}
```

Or you can pass it as an object and cast later like:

```
private void MyMethod(Object myDictionary) { 
   string color = ((Dictionary<string,string>)myDictionary)["color"];
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If from the syntax you are referring to .NET then it would be as simple as passing any other parameter into a method

```
AMethod(Dictionary<string,string> dictionary)
{
//  Stuff
}
```

If you are doing a new inside the AMethod to create a new dictionary then don't forget to add a "ref".

Comment: ok, but i pass dictionary object as an argument to some method. As i have already decleared Dictionary object and have put some keys and vlues in it

Comment: @user: the calling code would just read `AMethod(myDictionary)`